# .NET Maui Build Error Could not find Microsoft.iOS

Tags: ios, publish, maui

I am on a PC Visual Studio CE 2022 attempting to archive and deploy for iOS. I am using the following command:

```
dotnet publish PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui -f net7.0-ios -c Release /p:ServerAddress=192.168.1.XXX /p:ServerUser='username' /p:TcpPort=58181 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true
```

The process builds and connects to my Macbook but then throws this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.1.1477\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(1738,3): error : Could not find Microsoft.iOS in /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.1.1477/
```

I am not quite sure where it is looking for /usr/local/share.... I assume that is on the Macbook.

Do I have to install that version of the SDK on the Macbook? If so how do I do that? (Not a mac user). I tried in Terminal

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.iOS.Sdk --version 16.1.1477
```

but it wants to add that to a specific project.

Comment: Isn't VS installing Xamarin.IOS on mac when you are pairing it with your mac? Not really a question..

Comment: That's what I thought but...then there's this error message.

Comment: Could this help? [Visual Studio Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/installation?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vsmac)

Comment: I have those options installed thanks

Comment: the error remains ?

Comment: Yes. Same error

Comment: Have you tried creating a new project using default template to see   if it works?

Comment: Did you use XCode14.2? XCode 14.2 is not supported now.

Comment: is 14.1 supported?

Comment: yes XCode 14.1 is supported now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I was missing the  /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory='/Users/{mac_os_username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/' parameter. For some reason it was not part of the cli string I copied. The error message doesn't help either, sends you down a rabbit hole.

Comment: In my case the mac_os_username was wrong in  /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory='/Users/{mac_os_username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/' parameter

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.2 is still working on and it's not supported yet by Visual Studio c. You could check the release note here [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes).

As an alternative, you could now try downgrading back to Xcode 14.1 and build the project. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I installed XCode 14.1 and received the same error.

Comment: Same thing happens with the default project.

Comment: Have you ever build it  successfully using build or run button instead of command line?

Comment: Yes I am able to build and deploy to my iPhone where the app runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is from Visual Studio in PC, I pair it to my Mac and it will automatically reinstall everything for me.

If somehow I cannot connect to my Mac or got some problem, I will do this step :

[1] --> in Mac
open "$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin"
--> move to trash the XMA folder

[2] -->in local windows
del %localappdata%\Temp\Xamarin\XMA

[3] Restart visual studio